# Pardot - Product Interest - Date Field Storing WHEN Interest Came

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-object, custom-field, customization, pardot

I find myself in a company that is implementing **Pardot** for it's Marketing efforts.

I've done a little research, but do not see references to what I want and hope that this is simple or at least do-able via some hack that is not outlandish.

When a form is submitted (Pardot Form OR using Form Handlers), we will have a hidden field to represent a Product Group (or specific Product) the submitter is interested in.   "**Product Interest**".

I do not like storing checkboxes for such data when a Date field is much more thorough (it also tells WHEN they had that interest, can be intersected with other data to do various things).

**What would I do to store such data in Pardot?**

In SF proper, I'll either be doing a custom object related to Account/Contact and Lead, with pairs of fields:

- Interest__c . . .   (text)
- Date_Of_Interest__c . . .   (date)

...or fields on those Objects, so assume (date fields):

- PI_Printers__c
- PI_Lanyards__c
- PI_Toner__c
- PI_Salami__c

In any case, I need to capture the date that they SUBMITTED THE FORM which included reference to "Printers" (example) and store it in Pardot to pass to SF.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question you can accomplish this by doing the following:

Create a custom text field for "Product Interest" and "Interest Date" and set them to appear on every form (I would set them as hidden, unless you want "Product Interest" to be selected by the user on the form)

You can capture Product Interest several ways (*user selected, dynamic, lead gen form link*). This is how you could do it for a lead gen form: You can set the Product Interest field value by adding in a url parameter to the url you are sending people to like so: `http://www.url.com/lp/?product_interest=myproduct` (*that will set the field named product interest to myproduct.*)

***Note:*** When you create the custom field you will set the field name. If you'd prefer you can set it to something short like, "pi" if you want to keep the URL shorter.

Then you can implement some code on your layout template to autofill the date on the form. Here is a code example using jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/7u065ot0/1/

Now, when a user submits a form they will also be submitting Product Interest and Interest Date.

Comment: You should include any relevant code here, not just a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Thanks - don't recall being notified of this answer.  I will be digging into this soon and reading it briefly, sounds very much like what I was interested in doing.

Comment: @AMM Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Accepting this answer;  we are not "there" yet (integration from archaic systems has taken months, nowhere near done due to business processes barely having been documented prior to my arrival).   In any case, the Date field (only) is possible, I now know this.  Thanks.